# pyspark groupby mean using dictionary variable

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to execute groupby mean of pyspark dataframe using mean function as dictionary variable.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
_func= {'mean' : F.mean}
df.groupby('name')._func['mean']()
```

But this fails with error

```
'AttributeError GroupedData object has no attribute _func'
```

I tried import mean function of GroupedData class from pyspark.sql.group too but it fails with same error.

How Can I fix this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the dictionary in `agg`.

```py
df = df.groupby('name').agg({'column_name': 'mean'})
```

If you want to use a dictionary of functions, use it like this,

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
_func= {'mean' : F.mean}
df = df.groupby('name').agg(_f['mean']())
```

EDIT:

According to your requirements as mentioned in comments, this the only solution I could come up with,

```py
df = df.groupby('name').agg(*[_f['mean'](x) for x in df.columns])
cols_to_delete = [_c for _c in df.columns if df.where(F.col(_c).isNotNull()).count() == 0]
df = df.drop(*cols_to_delete)
```

Comment: This is not I want  and I am working on pyspark dataframe , not pandas

Comment: Yes this is for a pyspark dataframe. You need to specify the column name on which you want to calculate `mean`.

Comment: groupby('name').mean() does on all columns (int or float dtypes columns)  without specifying. I wanted similar to that.

Comment: I could not find a straight forward answer to your problem. Please check the edit.